# Do all devices under Linux have a device node?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, devices

I know that each device on Linux is either a `char` or `block` or `network` device.

Do all physical devices that exist on Linux have a device node under the `/dev` directory? I'm not talking here about network devices, I'm talking about any other device.

Answer (score 1):

On systems with udev (that's more or less all for several years) every recognized device has an entry in `/dev`.

These entries can be deleted, though. But (I guess) without a device file it is not possible for a userland process to access a device. Of course, for a device file to work it just needs the correct major and minor number. It doesn't matter what the name (or path) of the device file is. `/root/foo` could be `/dev/sda`.